# Hide title on Bottom Tabs Navigator

Tags: react-native

I'm using `Bottom Tabs Navigator` but it has some title that i'm not able to hide:

[image]

I saw there is `tabBarShowLabel` but nothing for the label particular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tabBarShowLabel` option is to specify whether or not you want to display the label inside the bottom tab with the icon.

You can use `headerShown` like this :

```
<Tab.Screen
  name="Navigator"
  component={YourComponent}
    options={() => {         // or just options={{headerShown: false}}
      return {
        headerShown: false,
        ...
      ),
    };
  }}
/>
```